# My Vue Js app refreshes on each single doc change

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Vue Js and Firebase to build a voting web app, the app contains units, and each unit has an "upvote" and "downvote" buttons.
my problem is that whenever a button is clicked the whole list of units refreshes, instead of changing the votes count only as it should. am I missing something with my Vue js code?

Html code:

```html
<div id="unitWrapper">
      <div v-for="request in requests" id="unit" >
          <iframe :src="request.text" id="spotifyEmbed" width="80" height="80" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
          <h2 id="title">{{ request.songN }}</h2>
          <div id="votes">
              <span  id="up" @click="upV(request.id)">
                <i class="fas fa-arrow-up fa-2x" v-if="request.isUpvoted" style="color: rgb(1, 187, 1);"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-arrow-up fa-2x" v-else style="color: #888;"></i>
                <p class="votesNumber" style="color: rgb(1, 187, 1);">{{ request.upVotes }}</p>
              </span>
              <span id="down"  @click="downV(request.id)">
                <i class="fas fa-arrow-down fa-2x" v-if="request.isDownvoted" style="color: red;"></i>
                  <i class="fas fa-arrow-down fa-2x" v-else style="color: #888;"></i>
                  <p class="votesNumber" style="color: red;">{{ request.downVotes }}</p>
              </span>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Js/Vue code:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#unitWrapper",
  data: {
    requests: [],
  },
  methods: {
    upV(id) {
      const upvote = firebase.functions().httpsCallable("upvote");
      upvote({ id: id }).catch((err) => {
        showNotification();
      });
    },
    downV(id) {
      const downvote = firebase.functions().httpsCallable("downvote");
      downvote({ id: id }).catch((err) => {
        showNotification();
      });
    },
  },
  created() {
    const ref = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("requests")
      .orderBy("upVotes", "desc");
    ref.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      let requests = [];
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        var obj = {};
        obj = {
          ...doc.data(),
          id: doc.id,
        };
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        if (user != null) {
          firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection("users")
            .doc(user.uid)
            .get()
            .then((val) => {
              if (val.exists) {
                  var res = val.data().upVotedOn.includes(doc.id)
                  var res2 = val.data().downVotedOn.includes(doc.id)
                  console.log(`${res2} - downvoted`);
                  obj.isUpvoted = res;
                  obj.isDownvoted = res2;
              } else {
                obj.isUpvoted = false;
                obj.isDownvoted = false;
              }
              requests.push(obj);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        } else {
          obj.isUpvoted = false;
          obj.isDownvoted = false;
          requests.push(obj);
        }
      });

      // console.log(requests);
      this.requests = requests;
    });
  },
});
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: I'm new to vue but my guess is vue refresh the whole app because it is written with a single component. Whenever there is a change in a property of data object the whole app rerender because the component rerender itself. Have you considered splitting each unit in a generic component ?

Comment: @OlivierCadoz can you explain more? I'm also new to Vue js

Comment: I'll try ! Your vue instance is compose by a data object and a template so whenever you upvote or downvote on a single unit vue rerender the whole template because it is one block. But I just remark the key attribute is missing. Vue needs it to optimise list rendering. Try adding v-bind:key="request.id" or :key="request.id" and tell me if anything has changed !
I would recommend reading this for more knowledge on list rendering : https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/list.html#maintaining-state

Comment: The key attribute binding has to be written on the same div as the v-for directive. It helps Vue to target the specific item concerned by  a change.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still the same, I also tried changing v-if to :class so I can toggle classes without removing elements from the dom, but it didn't solve it

Comment: Then you may try to isolate your unit in a generic component that would manage upvote and downvote in itself  and so endorse the rerender. you would only have the concerned component that would rerender itself.